# Facing a problem regarding LDA interfacing in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I want to classify data with run time values in LDA algorithm in Python. Below is the code i tried but model.fit(X, y) gives error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis 
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Adil Arshad\Desktop\dataacquistion py\adc.xlsx')
#print (df)
last_column = df.iloc[: , -1:]
print("Last Column Of Dataframe : ")
print(last_column)
new_last = str(last_column)
print(type(new_last))

df.columns = ['TL', 'CL', 'TR', 'CR', 'new_last']
#view first six rows of DataFrame
df.head()
print(df)

X = df[['TL', 'CL', 'TR', 'CR', 'new_last']]
y = df['new_last']

#Fit the LDA model
model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
model.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your dataset and check if it has no nan values. Always perform EDA to check if you have missing values, incorrect entries, object instead of string values, etc...

Use this function to return a cleaned df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def clean_dataset(df):
    assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame), "df needs to be a pd.DataFrame"
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df.reset_index()
    indices_to_keep = ~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)
    
    return df[indices_to_keep].astype(np.float64)

clean_df = clean_dataset(df)
```